# Convert ASCII table char into ASCII table decimals

Tags: android, c++, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, ascii

I am working with Arduino and Android. Trying to send data from Android phone to an ESP32 device using BLE. I am having issues receiving data from the Android side.

For example, I would write to the ESP32 with the following Java code on Android:

```
mBluetoothLeService.writeCustomCharacteristic(0xFFFF);
```

where writeCustomCharacteristic() function is below:

```
 public void writeCustomCharacteristic(int value) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    /*check if the service is available on the device*/
    BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("00001110-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
    if(mCustomService == null){
        Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service not found");
        return;
    }
    /*get the read characteristic from the service*/
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic mWriteCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00000001-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
    mWriteCharacteristic.setValue(value,android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8,0);
    if(mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mWriteCharacteristic) == false){
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to write characteristic");
    }
}
```

Now, on the Arduino side, I want to receive exactly 0xFFFF, but it gave me garbage characters.

Following line is where ESP32 receives data, data is contained in rxValue:

```
 class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
  std::string rxValue = pCharacteristic->getValue();

  if (rxValue.length() > 0) {
    Serial.println("*********");
    Serial.print("Received Value: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < rxValue.length(); i++)
      Serial.print(rxValue[i]);

    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("*********");
  }
}
};
```

My question is, how do I translate that garbage character back into 0xFFFF?
I tried to do `int(rxValue[i])` or `byte(rxValue[i])`, but that only gave me 255, now how do I get the second byte?

Also, rxValue[0] has the data, other indexes are null.

writeCustomCharacteristic() function is the same as the tutorial, did not make any changes. 
Here is the [link](https://github.com/nkolban/ESP32_BLE_Arduino/blob/master/examples/BLE_uart/BLE_uart.ino) to the arduino code, it's from the esp32 library example.

**Solution**
Following Barns's suggestion, I just change the data format to something bigger like FORMAT_UINT16 shown below.

```
mWriteCharacteristic.setValue(value,android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16,0);
```

From this, I was able to receive actually data from android side.

Comment: I don't see a `writeCustomCharacteristic()` method in the framework. I do however see a `writeCharacteristic()`. Could you provide a reference to the method you are using?

Comment: @Barns I followed this link and added that function [click here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/how-to-communicate-with-a-custom-ble-using-an-android-app/)

Comment: It would be helpful to everyone reading you question (both for people trying to provide a solution and looking for a solution) if you had provided this custom method in your post. Please edit your question and add the code you are using.

Comment: Like I commented above. Please edit your post and add the code you are using to send the data. The link you provided may not exist in the years to come (or the code in the link may change), so posting the exact code you are using will help people in the future. In addition to that, external links are frown upon here at SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having this issue because the code you are using to send your data (which you apparently have taken from an online tutorial) does not fit the size of the data you are sending.

You are only receiving `255` because the code you are using to send your data is using the characteristic value format type sint8  `FORMAT_UINT8` (which the 255 obviously reflects), but the data you are sending (0xFFFF) is at least uint16, thus you should be using `FORMAT_UINT16` (the characteristic value format type for uint16).

Please familiarize yourself with the Android Documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#writeCharacteristic(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic)

and also this link in order to better understand how to set the characteristics you will be sending

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html

In order to better understand the possibilities and limitations.

**--Disclaimer--**

Until you post the actual code you are using this answer is just an attempt to explain what you are experiencing.

Comment: I added the arduino code in my questions. Thank you for the help btw.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figure it out, just need to change uint8 format to something :bigger. 
  mWriteCharacteristic.setValue(value,android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16,0);